# How to pass JSON from android to react native using bundle

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to send a JSONObeject from the Android native to react-native using bundle.
I'm using the following method to call the react-native side -

reactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager,
String moduleName,
@Nullable Bundle initialProperties)

The JSONOBject I'm getting contains nested elements including JSONArray.
I tried converting the JSONObject to a Bundle using the following code, but I'm getting the following error on the react-native side:

[image]

```
  Bundle devicesBundle = convertJsonToBundle(cardDataJsonObject);
  Bundle props = new Bundle();
  props.putBundle("devices", devicesBundle);


 public static Bundle convertJsonToBundle(JSONObject json){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        try {
            Iterator<String> iterator = json.keys();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = iterator.next();
                Object value = json.get(key);
                if (value instanceof String) {
                    bundle.putString(key, (String) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
                    bundle.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Long) {
                    bundle.putLong(key, (Long) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                    bundle.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Float) {
                    bundle.putFloat(key, (Float) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                    bundle.putDouble(key, (Double) value);
                } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                    bundle.putBundle(key, convertJsonToBundle((JSONObject) value));
                } else if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                    addArrayToBundle(bundle, key, (JSONArray) value);
                } else {
                    bundle.putString(key, value.getClass().getSimpleName());
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bundle;

    }

    private static void addArrayToBundle(Bundle bundle, String key, JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
        if (jsonArray.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Object firstObject = jsonArray.get(0);
        if (firstObject instanceof String) {
            String[] array = new String[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                array[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
            }
            bundle.putStringArray(key, array);
        } else if (firstObject instanceof Integer) {
            int[] array = new int[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                array[i] = jsonArray.getInt(i);
            }
            bundle.putIntArray(key, array);
        } else if (firstObject instanceof Long) {
            long[] array = new long[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                array[i] = jsonArray.getLong(i);
            }
            bundle.putLongArray(key, array);
        } else if (firstObject instanceof Boolean) {
            boolean[] array = new boolean[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                array[i] = jsonArray.getBoolean(i);
            }
            bundle.putBooleanArray(key, array);
        } else if (firstObject instanceof Float) {
            boolean[] array = new boolean[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                array[i] = jsonArray.getBoolean(i);
            }
            bundle.putBooleanArray(key, array);
        } else if (firstObject instanceof Double) {
            double[] array = new double[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                array[i] = jsonArray.getDouble(i);
            }
            bundle.putDoubleArray(key, array);
        } else if (firstObject instanceof JSONObject) {
            Parcelable[] array = new Parcelable[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                array[i] = convertJsonToBundle(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
            }
            bundle.putParcelableArray(key, array);
        }
    }
}
```